# How do I calculate Pressure drop across relief valve and then force on piston?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, cutting, drilling

So, I'm designing a basic downhole hydraulic tool cutter of an OD = 5 1/2 in., and my tool contains a relief valve and a piston. I am trying to calculate pressure drop across the relief valve so that I can calculate the force on piston that activates the knives. Please help me how can I achieve this.
Q, flow rate =  30 L/s
Pressure = 25 MPa

I haven't completed the drawing yet, but I'm referring to this design. I was suggested to add a valve and a spring.
[image]

Comment: A drawing or sketch of the system wtih relavant dimensions would be helpful.

Comment: Have you used a standard orifice calculation formula and found that it is wrong?

Comment: @J.Ari I found how to calculate it, but I am a bit confused. If I'm adding a valve, and a nozzle in the piston, am I supposed to calculate the pressure drop across the valve or the nozzle? And where should I actually place the valve? between the piston and the top sub? It's a bit confusing for me... I really hope you can suggest me something on that.

Comment: Do you have a sketch of the actual device showing the new and existing parts? We also need to know the fluid paths and the dimensions of the various fluid paths.